# Does Swift whole module optimization cause any issues when debugging?

Tags: swift, optimization

Some time ago (a year?) we ran into problems with debug builds that had [whole module optimization](https://swift.org/blog/whole-module-optimizations/) enabled. When tracing, the debugger would jump to unexpected addresses. Since then, we've been shy about enabling this on our debug builds. We do enable it for our release builds.

Is anyone aware of any existing --- even subtle --- issues with debugging an executable that has been optimized this way?

Or, conversely, has everything been working fine for you with this configuration?

Comment: I don't enable optimisation of any sort on debug builds. Any kind of optimisation that causes there no longer to be a one-to-one relationship between the compiled code and the source can be problematic for running the debugger.

Comment: I agree. We're getting pushed to speed up our Jenkins builds for debug. We currently have zero optimizations for that build. I'm going to push back on this for the reason you stated.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand it should not cause issues as whole module optimisation mainly means that Swift knows what it can directly address ( a straight up `_call` ) compared to a `VTable lookup` as well as reduce the costly retain release cycles.

Similar to this, it is a good idea in general to use access control in swift right when you writing your code. privatizie everything unless you really need to access it outside. Use `final` on classes that don't need subclassing etc.

Usually when you enter the assembly view in Xcode is because of symbols missing for the debugger on libraries being called.

A small tip for debugging: I recently found a bug in my own code when implementing a TLS socket by simply looking up the address and the referenced method, downloading the source and looking up what was missing or causing the issue.

Now that said, in general it will greatly increase debug build times so do you have any reasons for running `-whmo` in debug?